# HTML5 history api: window.history.back() loses history.state

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I'm using the html5 history api, I have a selectbox with categories, when the category is changed I push the id to the history state:

```
// ....
if (newValue) 
{
  history.pushState({ selectedCategoryId: newValue }, "Blog Posts");
}
```

When I leave the page and I press the browsers back button, the category id is still in the history.state, BUT when I click this link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();">← Go back</a>
```

Then the state is not preserved, also when I use this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">← Go back</a>
```

It doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? I'm using IE11 on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a day of programming I thought back on this problem, suddenly I thought that the # in href is basically an empty hash and probably overrides the state.

So I removed `href="#"` and now it works!

Comment: Changing the href to "javascript:window.history.go(-1)" would do the same as the onclick attribute.